# Stream.last callback never firing

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, rxdart

I'm writing my Flutter app with a BLoC pattern. And what I want is pretty simple: show a TextField with the last value from a stream as an initial value.

There is the simple bloc:

```
class MyBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<String> _titleController;
  Stream<String> get outTitle => _titleController.stream;
  Sink<String> get inTitle => _titleController.sink;

  MyBloc(Model model) {
    _titleController = BehaviorSubject(seedValue: model.title); 
  }
}
```

And the view with a FutureBuilder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var bloc = /* get the bloc from a widgets' hierarchy */
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: bloc.outTitle.last,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextField(
        controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
          TextEditingValue(text: snapshot.data ?? 'null')
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
```

The problem is that the FutureBuilder calls the builder only once with null data and "waiting" connection state.

What I tried:

1. Replace `FutureBuilder` with `StreamBuilder` and `outTitle.last` with `outTitle.last.asStream()`;
2. Call `outTitle.last.then()` outside widgets and from bloc constructor;
3. Change signature of `outTitle` to `ValueObservable` and call `last.wrapped`;
4. Change Rx's `BehaviorSubject` to vanilla `StreamController`;
5. Add to stream some values before building the view;

Nothing happens. 
Just streams with `StreamBuilder`s work well, but it is impossible to get the last value from `last` property.

Where can the problem lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last` is only emitted when the stream is closed. Otherwise the stream can't know what the last event is.

When you call

```
_titleController.close()
```

`last` will emit a value.

Comment: Thank you, Günter. The `last` description is a little bit confusing.

Comment: I found many things about streams confusing but it gets better ;-)